# Series $\sum_0^{\infty} a_n$ and $\sum_0^{\infty} b_n$ are convergent series then so is $\sum_0^{\infty} c_k$ where $c_k= \sum_{l=0}^{k}a_lb_{k-l}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Series $\sum\limits_0^{\infty} a_n$ and $\sum\limits_0^{\infty} b_n$ are convergent series then so is $\sum\limits_0^{\infty} c_k$ where  $c_k= \sum\limits_{l=0}^{k}a_lb_{k-l}$

**Solution I tried**:  I tried to prove this using a counterexample like $$a_n\frac{(-1)^n}{(n+1)^{\frac{1}{3}}}$$ and $$b_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{(n+2)^{\frac{2}{3}}}$$ then after that we get $$c_k=\frac{(-1)^{2n}}{(n+1)}$$  which is divergent,  but I contrardict this with an example, is there any way we can prove this divergent or convergent with proper definition?

Please help

Thank you

Comment: You could see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product

Comment: If $a_k$ and $b_k$ are what you say, I don't think $c_k$ is.

Comment: Yes I had forgotten, you need that one of the series converges absolutely, an assumption that seems to be missing in your statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider
$$a_n = b_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n+1}}.$$
Then
$$c_n = (-1)^n \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{(k+1)(n-k-1)}},$$
and $k+1, n-k-1$ are both less than $n+1$, so we have
$$|c_n| \geq \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{n+1} = 1,$$
and so $c_n$ does not go to $0$. Hence $\sum c_n$ diverges.